# Как передавать данные каждые 15 секунд?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Есть приложение, в котором получаю данные с `EditText` и GPS и отправляю в БД MySQL удаленно через `HttpURLConnection`. Это надо делать через каждые 15 секунд после нажатия на кнопку. Всё готово и работает, но приложение зависает, когда делаю бесконечный цикл. Что делать?

```
Sender s = new Sender(MainActivity.this, urlAddress, lat, nameTxt, posTxt,
        teamTxt, idTxt, numTxt);
s.execute();
```

Comment: Действительно, а почему бы не зависать. Шедуль по периоду в 15 секунд недодумались написать?

Comment: а что такое шедуль ?

Comment: Запуск потока, в данном случаии scheduleAtfixedRate(new Task(), 0, 15000);

Comment: В чем его суть ? можете как ответ формулировку дать ?Я с ним не работал незнаю для чего он покажите и кратко о нем скажте дальше уже сам запилю знания

Comment: А Вам конкретно пакет concurrent и класс ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor вообще ниочем не говорит?

Comment: Хорошо спасибо на том что откликнулись и дали направение!Благодарю

Comment: @GenCloud сделайте ваш ответ "ответом". Т.к. данный вопрос будет сохранен в архиве и в будующем было проще найти ответ на данный вопрос. Спасибо! elik , если вы найдете ответ на свой вопрос, который будет отличаться - будьте добры, тоже оставьте свой ответ тут и пометьте его галочкой "ответ".

Comment: Хорошо я щас пока ищу, но как найду поделюсь

Comment: @elik у вас в вопросе было и "15 секунд", и "15 минут". Вы уж определитесь, пожалуйста. Я оставил вариант "15 секунд", но, может, я не угадал.

Comment: Угадали ,я усталый и невимательный простите Регент

Comment: @GenCloud к чему столь агрессивный тон?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно делать вот так, например:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private boolean weNeedToContinue = true;

private void doSomethingPeriodically() {
    // TODO здесь делай свою работу

    if (weNeedToContinue) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doSomethingPeriodically();
            }
        }, 15000);
    }

}
```

Обратите внимание, что работа будет выполняться в главном (UI) потоке. Выполнять взаимодействие с сервером из главного потока опасно.

Comment: Спасибо !Я примерно сделал также только в потоке запускаю еще  поток )

Comment: Для этого можно создать параллельный поток LooperThread, и постить handlerom туда.

Answer (score 3):

Для таких задач в Android есть два класса, это `JobScheduler` (доступен только с 21 api) и `GcmNetworkManager`. Я думаю вам лучше на последний вариант посмотреть. Вот пример [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-gcmnetworkmanager)